# Coldfusion 'thank you' page allows user to refresh unlimited times

Tags: cfml

Hi guys I need some advice please.

Our payment gateway sends back some data when an order is succesfully posted that is included in the url string.

The only problem is users are refreshing the page and sending through a bunch of cfmail commands each time they refresh the thank you page!

Which is better for our security, to setup a redirect to our home page shortly after this page is loaded, to setup a way to stop the user loading the page more than once or to strip out the order info so the user can't click refresh?

Below is a sample url that the payment gateway generates upon a succesful transaction.

```
http://www.ourwebsitename.com/ConfirmationPage.cfm?cartinfo=^XXXX^1&orderinfo=Customer^Name^Billing Name^Billing^Line^1^Town^Postcode^websitename^Order^Amount^&responsesitesecurity=SECUREHASHCODE&thisorderid=OURORDERID
```

What are people thoughts on securing this page?

Comment: Assume that they will do it and write your program to handle it.  Simon's answer has some good suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I've addressed this in the past is to do the following

1. On any page that the user is shown, try not to have any of the logic that actually does anything.  Display logic only on display pages
2. At the end of the checkout process, send the email, and then use `<cflocation>` to redirect to the confirmation page
3. Add some check-bit to the session or whatever you use to keep track of the user to flag that the email has already been sent
4. If you REALLY don't want users resending the email twice, use a `<cflock>` and confirm that the flag mentioned in #3 hasn't been flagged inside the `<cflock>` (to make sure it hasn't been sent by the process that locked it)

This should help reduce / remove the impact of the user refreshing.  When I've had this in the past it's been due to people placing logic on the output pages that should really have been on one of the pages that the user doesn't get shown (due to them silently redirecting)

Comment: Thankyou for the help, I followed your advice as follows-:

SET flag for email sent in new column
CFIF condition to see if email has been sent
Redirected to the thankyou page using javascript passing the form elements of the order through to the new page, CFLOCATION wouldn't pass thorugh the form elements...

Sorted now, thankyou very much :-)

Comment: With cflocation you can pass data through the url, but if it's an order system, there may be sensitive data, so good choice.

Comment: I believe the way I got around that was to ensure data, especially sensitive data, only had to be submitted once before being stored/encrypted.  Anything on a location string was deemed "public" and so able to go on the url just as well as form.   The benefit of using cflocation is that the user doesn't see the processing page and so cannot refresh it specifically which is still a risk when forwarding with js :)  Good to hear it worked well for you though.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you add a `confirmation_email_sent`-column to your order table in the database, and then set this flag the first time you send the email. If the users refreshes the page, you will notice that this flag is already set, and can then skip sending the email. If there are other side effects than the e-mail-sending, then these should probably be mitigated in the same way.